# pickle is not working in a proper way

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, pickle

```
import nltk
import pickle

input_file=open('file.txt', 'r')
input_datafile=open('newskills1.txt', 'r')

string=input_file.read()
fp=(input_datafile.read().splitlines())

def extract_skills(string):
    skills=pickle.load(fp)
    skill_set=[]
    for skill in skills:
        skill= ''+skill+''
    if skill.lower() in string:
        skill_set.append(skill)
    return skill_set

if __name__ == '__main__':
    skills= extract_skills(string)
print(skills)
```

I want to print the `skills` from file but, here `pickle` is not working.
It shows the error:

> _pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted

Answer (score 3):

The file containing the pickled data must be written and read as a binary file. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#examples) for examples.

Your extraction function should look like:

```
def extract_skills(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as inputFile:
        skills = pickle.load(inputFile)
```

Of course, you will need to dump your data into a file open as binary as well:

```
def save_skills(path, skills):
    with open(path, 'wb') as outputFile:
        pickle.dump(outputFile, skills)
```

Additionally, the logic of your main seems a bit flawed.
While the code that follows `if __name__ == '__main__'` is only executed when the script is run as main module, the code that is **not** in the main should only be static, ie definitions.
Basically, your script should not **do** anything, unless run as main.
Here is a cleaner version.

```
import pickle

def extract_skills(path):
    ...

def save_skills(path, skills):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputPath = "skills_input.pickle"
    outputPath = "skills_output.pickle"

    skills = extract_skills(inputPath)
    # Modify skills
    save_skills(outputPath, skills)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it's give the error:AttributeError: module 'pickle' has no attribute 'dump'

Comment: @JayPratapPandey I'm lacking information. Pickle does have a `dump` attribute, regardless of Python's version.

Comment: Can i load txt file in pickle?

Comment: it gives the error :UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted